# How to get back the object id after POST method using Sequelize and send it to frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sequelize.js

I try to post a new object in my MySQL database in React using Sequelize and I have this route:

```
app.post("/event", checkAuthorization, async (req, res) => {

    let new_event = {
        title: req.body.title,
        description: req.body.description,
        label: req.body.label,
        day: req.body.day,
        user_id: req.body.user_id,
    };

    let response = {};

    Events.create(new_event)
        .then(() => {
            response.msg = 'Adaugat cu succes!';
            response.added = 1;
            res.send(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            response.msg = err;
            response.added = 0;
            res.send(response);
        });

});
```

- checkAuthorization is to check if user is logged id

My problem is: I send an object without an id because is auto-increment in my database and all I want is after I post this object in database, to return to frontend the object id created by database and I don't know how to write that.

Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```
Events.create(new_event)
        .then((event) => {
            response.id=event.id
            response.msg = 'Adaugat cu succes!';
            response.added = 1;
            res.send(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            response.msg = err;
            response.added = 0;
            res.send(response);
        });
```

you will get the created object as a parameter

Comment: I tried but returns me the all object without id and I don't know why...  {id: null, title: 'fdfa', description: 'dggsd', label: 'red', day: 1645567200000, …}

Comment: and there is an id in the table?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to used:

```
Events.create(new_event)
        .then((event) => {
            console.log(event);
            response.msg = 'Adaugat cu succes!';
            response.added = 1;
            res.send(response);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            response.msg = err;
            response.added = 0;
            res.send(response);
        });
```

And this is the output:

```
event {
  dataValues: {
    id: null,
    title: 't',
    description: 'dsada',
    label: 'green',
    day: 1645653600000,
    user_id: 2
  },
  _previousDataValues: {
    title: 't',
    description: 'dsada',
    label: 'green',
    day: 1645653600000,
    user_id: 2,
    id: null
  },
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: true,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    attributes: undefined,
    include: undefined,
    raw: undefined,
    silent: undefined
  },
  isNewRecord: false,
  null: 23
}
```

That 'null: 23' is my id and I don't know why database returns me the id like that... Can someone explain me?

Comment: whats the name of your id column? can you share your model?

Comment: Model is here: https://ibb.co/Wvpp8sf

Answer (score 0):

You will get easily user inserted data using below code

```
const result = await Events.create(new_event);
console.log(result.id);
```